# Não consigo inserir texto simples no mysql com coluna text

Tags: mysql, sql

Não estou conseguindo fazer um update simples em uma tabela que contém uma coluna *TEXT*.
Coloquei um texto espanhol simples porém o sql me retorna erro dizendo que linha é grande demais. Porém é uma frase muito pequena. Segue o código do erro:

**Erro consulta SQL:  Editar**

```
UPDATE ppplaw.sobre SET pol_gestao_esp = 'Para la continuidad de
la excelencia en la prestación de servicios jurídicos y de la
satisfacción de nuestros clientes, colocamos todos los esfuerzos'
WHERE sobre.id = 1
```

**Mensagens do MySQL:**

```
 #1118 - Row size too large. The maximum row size for the used table type,
 not counting BLOBs, is 8126. You have to change some columns to TEXT or BLOBs
```

Comment: Sobre na verdade é a tabela, o campo é pol_gestao_esp que eu não defini tamanho, está pegando o tamanho padrão para o tipo TEXT.

Comment: Tenta ver tambem o tamanha da quantidade de caracteres que tu configurou, possa ser que o tamanho configurado esteja sendo excedido.

Comment: Lendo a mensagem de erro, o problema não está no tamanho do campo, mas sim no tamanho total do registo(*row*), que excede o tamanho máximo para o tipo de tabela(*table*) usada.

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que mostra o erro, a sua coluna está tipada como "table", o que não permite a inserção de texto.
Dá um `show columns from _nomeTabela_` pra ver se o tipo chegou certo.

Outra alternativa seria o collation da sua tabela. Se o texto está em UTF-8, ele tem, na prática, 8 bytes de tamanho, o que são 4x mais do que o texto codificado em ANSI ou Latin-1, padrões do MySQL.